# Line 50: Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents

Tags: reactjs, jsx

> Parsing Error: Unterminated JSX contents. Not sure why it keeps on saying that I need another tag. Also, the one thing that I have trouble with is what to do with the self-closing HTML tags. I don't know what to do with them for JSX.

I have tried to match all of the tags and used Atom to create an Html file and a bracket matcher. I have no idea why it keeps giving me this error. I thought to add a starting tag for the self-closing tags.

```
import React from 'react';
import linkedinIcon from "./footer-component/linkedin-icon.png";

export default class Resume extends React.Component {
render(){
return (
<div className="container">
  <div className="col-md-12">
    <h1>Résumé</h1>
    <h3>SUMMARY</h3>
    <p>Passionate front-end web developer with 3 years of experience using JavaScript, HTML5, CSS, Bootstrap and Javascript frameworks to build the users experience and user interface for client-facing webpages. Specializes in React, HTML, Bootstrap,
      and CSS</p>
    <hr>
    </hr>
    <h3>Technical Skills</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Front-end</li>
      <ul>
        <li>HTML</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>Bootstrap 4</li>
        <li>JavaScript</li>
        <li>jQuery</li>
        <li>Embedded JavaScript</li>
        <li>REACT</li>
      </ul>
      <li>Other</li>
      <ul>
        <li>Git</li>
        <li>GitHub</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <h3>Work Experience</h3>
    <p>Operations Summer Intern, Benetech | Palo Alto, California | 2019 - 2019</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Created more than 20 landing pages in HTML5, CSS3, and Bootstrap 4</li>
      <li>Implemented CSS/Bootstrap to design multiple responsive web pages</li>
      <li>Maintained front-end code and documentation standards</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    </hr>
    <h3>Education</h3>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-2">
        Expected in 06/2020
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-10">
        <p><b>High School Diploma</b>
          <br></br>
          <b>Fusion Academy</b> - Palo Alto</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
    } // END OF RENDER
    } // END OF Resume
```

> Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents. Hope errors are gone.

Comment: First two div elements are not closed. Also the right way to add horizontal line tag is using self-closing tag <hr />.
Passionate front-end web developer with 3 years of experience using JavaScript... Funny 

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close two top `div` elements (`.container` and `.col-md-12`)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two `</div>` tags at the end for `.container` and `.col-md-12`.

Also, you should probably use `<hr />` only, without the closing tag. [HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.3) says:

> *Start tag*: **required**, *End tag*: **forbidden**

`<hr></hr>` is valid XHTML, but you should use the above for compatibility reasons.